# Vertex AI invoke endpoint failed. ERROR: Prediction failed. Please contact cloudml-feedback@google.com

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have deployed my App on Vertex AI endpoint. The endpoint is created successfully and I am getting "Active" status. But when I try to invoke the endpoint, I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Prediction failed. Please contact cloudml-feedback@google.com",
        "status": "INTERNAL"
    }
}
```

POST Request URL: `https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/endpoints/${ENDPOINT_ID}:predict`

Header: I am passing the required header i.e., Content-Type: application/json and Authorization token.

Body:

```
{
  "instances": [{
      "image_path": "https://github.com/naqishah13/multilabelimages/blob/main/movie-poster-1.jpg?raw=true"
      }
  ]
}
```

Here is my flask code that I am using for prediction:

```
@app.route('/get_movie_genres/', methods=['POST'])
def main():
    request_json = request.get_json()
    request_instances = request_json['instances']
    image_path = request_instances[0]['image_path']
    predicted_genres = predict_(image_path)
    output = {'predictions':
               [
                   {
                       'predicted_genres' : prediction
                   }
               ]
           }
    return jsonify(output)
```

I have saved some images on github and I am using those images (via github path) in order to do the movie genre prediction.

Am I doing something wrong? what might be causing the issue?

Comment: I suspect that the github image path could be to blame. Try to upload some sample files to GCS and set the blob path as the image_path. You will need to write a bit of code and give your service account permissions to the bucket in order to download the blob.

Comment: As the error suggested, when you get internal errors in a managed solution like this the recommended action is contacting support. It is likely that they can get you more detailed information, and perhaps they will make the product more robust or at least find a way to surface an error that would allow users to troubleshoot the problem themselves.